# In C, memory allocating fails, why?

Tags: c

```
int x;
int komsuSayisi;//adjanceny matrix
int **arkadas;
int t;
int komsu[24][24];

scanf("%d",&t);
**arkadas = (int **)malloc( t*sizeof( int* )); //allocating rows
for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    x=0;
    arkadas[i] = (int *)malloc( t*sizeof(int) ); //allocating cow temporarily
    for(j=0; j<t; j++)
    {
        komsu[i][j]=fark(kelime[i],kelime[j]); //fark returns 1 or 0.
        //so i put those 1 ones to another matrix,arkadas
        if(komsu[i][j]==1){
            komsuSayisi++;
            arkadas[i][x]=j;
            x++;
        }
        arkadas[i] = (int *) realloc(arkadas[i], x);
        //real allocating here
    }
```

It gives error and shut downs.There is nothing wrong. What i want is adjanceny is too big to search so i will easily search the `"1"` ones with this matrix.

Comment: Are you sure you need `**arkadas` before doing your malloc? I was under the impression you just needed `arkadas` without the '*'s

Comment: How is it failing? Where? Certainly you are not checking for allocation errors.

Comment: Ok i found. arkadas[i] = (int *) realloc(arkadas[i], x); should be after for, i thought so but i mistook with if {

Comment: You wrote, ***"There is nothing wrong."***.... so, why are you asking a question?  I'm guessing that clearly *something* is wrong!

Comment: @abelenky wanted to say something similar, but then I thought it is actually helping - when someone claims "nothing is wrong" you could/should expect *any* number of mistakes. Still +1.

Comment: @abelenky If the program crashed there is obviously something wrong. OP is asking the question because he can't find the error in his code, i.e. for him the code is not wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
**arkadas = (int **)malloc( t*sizeof( int* ));
```

should be

```
arkadas = malloc( t*sizeof( int* ));
```

`**arkadas` dereferences an uninitialised pointer, resulting in you trying to write to an unpredictable address.  You don't own the memory at this address so it isn't safe to try and write to it.

The second form assigns the address of an array of pointers to the local variable `arkadas`; this is what need to do.

Later in your program

```
if(komsu[i][j]==1){
    komsuSayisi++;
    arkadas[i][x]=j;
    x++;
}
arkadas[i] = (int *) realloc(arkadas[i], x);
```

code inside the `if` condition attempts to write to `arkadas[i]` before you allocate it.  This also invokes undefined behaviour and will likely crash.  You can avoid the crash by removing the line `arkadas[i][x]=j;` and swapping your `realloc` call for `malloc` (you need the address of a previous allocation before you can call `realloc`)

```
if(komsu[i][j]==1){
    komsuSayisi++;
    x++;
}
arkadas[i] = malloc(x*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Not only it is not safe to write here, it also doesn't do what it supposed to (not setting `arkadas` to "array of t pointers").

Comment: I will make t rows and each row has dynamic size, = x.

Comment: @user3721298 That's fine.  The way to allocate the initial array of pointers is to make the change I describe above

Comment: There is another error later in your program.  See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I see

```
 komsuSayisi++;
```

You didn't paste the whole code but probably thats what is crashing your program... I don't see any initializing previous to that increment....

this plus the deferentiation posted on the other answer